Can't access API url hosted in Docker
What am I missing here?
I built my docker image:
sudo docker build -t meicrosoft-billing-api -f src/Meicrosoft.Billing.API/Dockerfile . --no-cache

with success.
Then I run my container with:
sudo docker run -d -e ConnectionStrings__OrderConnection="Server=[::1];Database=MeicrosoftBilling;User id=sa;Password=...;TrustServerCertificate=True" \
    -p 8080:8080 \
    meicrosoft-billing-api:latest

This is my dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/Meicrosoft.Billing.API/Meicrosoft.Billing.API.csproj", "src/Meicrosoft.Billing.API/"]
COPY ["src/Meicrosoft.Billing.Application/Meicrosoft.Billing.Application.csproj", "src/Meicrosoft.Billing.Application/"]
COPY ["src/Meicrosoft.Billing.Domain/Meicrosoft.Billing.Domain.csproj", "src/Meicrosoft.Billing.Domain/"]
COPY ["src/Meicrosoft.Billing.Infra.CrossCutting/Meicrosoft.Billing.Infra.CrossCutting.csproj", "src/Meicrosoft.Billing.Infra.CrossCutting/"]
COPY ["src/Meicrosoft.Billing.Infra/Meicrosoft.Billing.Infra.csproj", "src/Meicrosoft.Billing.Infra/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./src/Meicrosoft.Billing.API/./Meicrosoft.Billing.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/Meicrosoft.Billing.API"
RUN dotnet build "./Meicrosoft.Billing.API.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./Meicrosoft.Billing.API.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Meicrosoft.Billing.API.dll"]

but I can't access it through the navigator, it says the page is not working, like its not running, but my container is running.
With docker ps:
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                        COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                  NAMES
container_id   meicrosoft-billing-api:latest                "dotnet Meicrosoft.B…"   5 minutes ago   Up 5 minutes   8080-8081/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, :::8080->80/tcp   vibrant_aryabhata

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.
I tried seeing if the port is in use, but its not. I tried rebuilding the image with no cache, recreating the container, accessing localhost:8080 and localhost:8081 and nothing. I also get the logs that the API is running:
sudo docker logs container_id:
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:8080
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app


Your docker ps shows that port 8080 is mapped to port 80 in the container and not 8080 as your docker run command says. Try killing the container and starting it again. It should show  0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp in docker ps.

@HansKilian yes, now it shows 8080->8080 but i stil cant access on localhost:8080, is there anything else i have to configure?

If you're trying to access the swagger page, then that is disabled by default as a container is not considered a development environment (the code that enables it is in Program.cs).
